# How to set the names based on a specific length in R

Tags: r

**This is just an example. My function is very complicated and the `setNames` is part of the function code**

I have a vector `xx` with `11` elements. I would like to give all the elements from `1:10` a special name. However, I would like to give the last element a different name. I tried `setNames` but it gave me the same names for all the elements.

```
xx <- c(1:11)
myfun <- function(i) {
  setNames(i, paste0("at level:", seq_along(i)))
}


> myfun(xx)
 at level:1  at level:2  at level:3  at level:4  at level:5  at level:6  at level:7  at level:8  at level:9 
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9 
at level:10 at level:11 
         10          11
```

I would like the name for the first `10` elements as `at level`. However, I would like to name the last element as a `Final element`.

Here is another try:

```
  myfun <- function(i){
  mm <- length(i)
fin <- setNames(i-1 , paste0("at level:", 1:(mm-1)))
fin}
myfun(xx)
```

But I got `NA` for the last element.

```
> myfun(xx)
 at level:1  at level:2  at level:3  at level:4  at level:5  at level:6  at level:7  at level:8  at level:9 
          0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8 
at level:10        <NA> 
          9          10
```

The length of my vectors is not always `11`it can be any number from `2: infinity`

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the last element from `seq_along(xx)` for example if you set the argument `n = -1` in `head()` as follows

```
setNames(xx ,
         nm = c(paste0("at level:", head(seq_along(xx), -1)), "Final element"))
#at level:1    at level:2    at level:3    at level:4    at level:5    at level:6    at level:7    at level:8    at level:9   at level:10 Final element 
#         1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8             9            10            11
```

from `?head`

> n:    a single integer. If positive, size for the resulting object: number of elements for a vector (including lists), rows for a matrix or data frame or lines for a function. If negative, all but the n last/first number of elements of x.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy, just do

```
xx <- 1:11
names(xx) <- c(paste(‘at level‘, 1:(length(xx)-1), sep=‘:‘), ‘final element‘)
```